# Java generics return generic paramaterized as more specific of two types?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I currently have a project where I'm filtering some Entities using a set of Classes implementing a generic `Filter<T extends Entity>` class, where T is the most specific Entity that specific filter will work on.  It's a bit verbose to be creating new Instances all the time, so I've also built a Builder. Everything was great except now where I'm trying to add the AndFilter to the builder.

Here's what my AndFilter looks like

```
public class AndFilter<T extends Entity> implements Filter<T>{
    private Filter<? super T> a;
    private Filter<? super T> b;

    public AndFilter(Filter<? super T> a, Filter<? super T> b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldInclude(T entity) {
        return a.shouldInclude(entity) && b.shouldInclude(entity);
    }
}
```

and here's the building function I've been trying to get to work (my builder is just default functions in the Filter interface)

```
public interface Filter<T extends Entity> {
    boolean shouldInclude(T entity);

    default AndFilter and(Filter<? extends Entity> other){
        return new AndFilter<>(this, other);
    }

    default Filter<T> not(){
        return new NotFilter<>(this);
    }
}
```

I need to be able to paramaterize the return of and(), but all attempt I've made have failed.  In theory, the AndFilter should be paramaterized to the type of this or other, whichever is more specific, but I don't know how I can do that, and I'm starting to think that it's simply not possible.  If it's not, any suggestions on alternate ways I could implement similar behavior (not having to call new AndFilter<>(x, y) to AND compare two filters) would be appreciated.

Edit: I have various Classes inheriting from Entity all with their own private properties.

Entity -> Animal -> Predator, Grazor

Entity -> Obstacle

Entity -> Plant

So I have a DistanceFilter implements Filter (since all entities have positiion and therefore distance), but I also have AggressionFilter implements Filter since only predators have an aggression property.  Checking if a predator satisfies both filters should be possible since the predator has all required properties, and it does work.  I can call new AndFilter<>(new DistanceFilter(), new AggressionFilter()) and it works fine, but when I try to put that initialization behind a function I can't get the return type to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve my own problem

```
default <F extends T> AndFilter<F> and(Filter<? super F> other){
    return new AndFilter<>(this, other);
}
```

Gotta give the function it's own generic type (F) which is at least the type of the current Filter, and then the other Filter has to be at most that type.  Returned AndFilter is paramaterized to that type.

Comment: Can you show an example usage of this, with the Entity classes?

Comment: So Entities are part of a Simulation, each time the simulation ticks, a tick function in each entity is called that does something. Tasks commonly involve getting the closest enemy of some other type, and so getNearestEntity(entities) was born, where entities is a collection of entities to look through. It was also very common to need an entity matching some criteria, because Grazers shouldn't run from an entity that's out of line of sight, and predators shouldn't try to mate with a predator if the other predator isn't mating. Because of this I created the Filter interface and implementations-

Comment: @Jason The line of code that I couldn't make work with my original attempts was `Predator p = findNearestEntity(predators, new CorpseFilter().not().and(new SightFilter(this));` which would find the nearest predator that isn't a corpse (when predators get low energy they become a corpse via boolean flag), and is also in line of sight of this predator.

Answer (score 0):

AndFilter has a parameterized type, AndFilter should be bound by T. AndFilter should be composed of Filter objects with the same type it is bound by, `T` which extends Entity.

```java
default AndFilter<T> and(Filter<? extends Entity> other){
    return new AndFilter<>(this, other);
}
```

```java
public class AndFilter<T extends Entity> implements Filter<T>{

    private Filter<T> a;

    private Filter<T> b;

    public AndFilter(Filter<T> a, Filter<T> b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Example implementation with a class `MyEntity` which extends Entity and has a single class member `name` of type String.

```java
        MyEntity foo = new MyEntity("Foo");

        MyEntity bar = new MyEntity("Bar");

        MyEntity fooBar = new MyEntity("FooBar");

        Filter<MyEntity> fooFilter = e -> e.name.contains("Foo");

        Filter<MyEntity> barFilter = e -> e.name.contains("Bar");

        Filter<MyEntity> fooBarFilter = fooFilter.and(barFilter);

        System.out.println(String.format("Foo: %s", fooFilter.shouldInclude(foo)));
        System.out.println(String.format("Bar: %s", barFilter.shouldInclude(bar)));
        System.out.println(String.format("FooBar: %s", fooBarFilter.shouldInclude(fooBar)));
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have a heirarchy of various Entities, there's Entity, there's Animal which inherits Entity, there's Grazer and Predator that both extend Animal.  There's also an Obstacle that extends Entity.  So some filters work for Predators, some work for Grazers, etc. Because of this, the filters in AndFilter could have different types because one applies to Entities and one applies to Predators.  For example, if I want to filter a predator specific trait such as .isAggressive() and an entity specific trait, like position, the And needs to take different types

Comment: What you need to do is have a subclass of Entity or interface that extends Entity, whatever Entity is, that implements some Aggressive interface. I.e; interface AggressiveEntity extends Entity. Then have Grazer and Predator extend AggressiveEntity. Then create a Filter of type AggressiveEntity like Filter<AggressiveEntity>.

Comment: I don't see how that's any different from having the Predator class and creating a Filter of type Filter<Predator>, such a filter would still have access to the required aggression property of Predators.  Aggression is a Predator specific trait, not animal specific.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't do that and ensure type safety if they're not of the same type. The compiler will have no idea what type of entity you're comparing. If you want this kind of flexibility you might need another class that chains filters and doesn't care about type safety.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking.  The only thing that makes me think it should be possible is the fact that the AndFilter itself works.  Because of that I feel like throwing the creation of an AndFilter behind a function shouldn't be this difficult unless for some reason it's just not possible

Comment: I figured out how to do it, take a look at my answer if you're curious

Comment: Great job, i'll chec kit out!